# Get position of mouse relative to hovered element in JS

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have an element let's say 10px height and 300px long.

On mouse enter/over I need to get the mouse cursor position relative to the element which I hovered.

For example, I mouseEnter the element in the middle(150px) of its width. I need to get information that it's 150/300 => 50% of this element.

Similar use case to mine we can find on youtube. When we hover over progress bar, the time of video appear above the bar. When we move mouse, the time follows the mouse.

Do you know the way I can count it based on properties inside mouseEvent?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this...

```
const x1 = 500
const x2 = 800
const y1 = 400
const y2 = 700
let resultX = 0, resultY = 0
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if(event.clientX >= x1 && event.clientX <= x2 && event.clientY >= y1 && 
     event.clientY <= y2){
       resultX = Math.round((event.clientX / x2) * 100)
       resultY = Math.round((event.clientY / y2) * 100)
  }
});
```